# Bitbake: What data structure is datastore?

Tags: python-3.x, bitbake

Following is a sentence from Bitbake user's manual:
"BitBake parses each recipe and append file located with BBFILES and stores the values of various variables into the datastore."

What data type is 'datastore' ?  Is it list or Tuple or Dictionary ? Or what data type is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work out the type of an object in python by executing `type(foo)` in the same environment. As for that specific type (datastore), a quick google indicates that it's neither a tuple or a dictionary, but a custom object with it's API documented [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#functions-for-accessing-datastore-variables).

Answer (score 2):

Bitbake's datastore is complex store of key+value pairs where keys also have flags (also key+value pairs). Its a custom structure written with a copy on write backend. It supports the idea of 'overrides' where one variable with special naming can override another. See https://git.openembedded.org/bitbake/tree/lib/bb/data_smart.py and https://git.openembedded.org/bitbake/tree/lib/bb/data.py within the codebase for the implementation, the Bitbake manual for information about how to use the data store and https://git.openembedded.org/bitbake/tree/lib/bb/tests/data.py for unittests of it.